# EKS deployment using CDK showing Kubernetes version error

Tags: python, kubernetes, aws-cloudformation, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I am trying to deploy my EKS cluster using Python CDK. I am following this(https://github.com/pahud/aws-cdk-python-workshop/tree/master/Lab6) link for implementation.
Everything is working good, but when I do 'cdk deploy', it is showing following error:
[image]

On Cloudformation console it is showing following error:

[image]

I tried changing version to 1.20, 1.20.4, 1.16, 1.16.5, etc(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/kubernetes-versions.html) in **cdk_pycon_eks_stack.py** in following way,

```
...................

# create the cluster
        cluster = aws_eks.Cluster(self, 'cluster',
                                  masters_role=eks_admin_role,
                                  vpc=vpc,
                                  default_capacity=0,
                                  version='1.20',
                                  output_cluster_name=True
                                  )

...........................................
```

, but then it shows following error:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!!
Thanks

---

Edit:

Additional images for reference in comments/Answers:
for `version = aws_eks.KubernetesVersion.of("v1_20")`
[image]

for `version = aws_eks.KubernetesVersion().V1_20`

[image]

Comment: As the code mentioned , try to use `version='1.14',`

Comment: When used 1.14 it is showing that the initial error of 'unsupported Kubernetes Version', see 1st and 2nd image

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need `aws-cdk-lib-2.0.0rc7` to support Kubernetes version 1.20 on EKS
- Then follow the post https://dev.to/vumdao/using-iam-service-account-instead-of-instance-profile-for-eks-pods-262p to up your EKS cluster with IAM service account
- Snippet:

```
        # Create EKS cluster
        self.eks_cluster = eks.Cluster(
            scope=self, id='EKSDevCluster',
            vpc=eks_private_vpc,
            default_capacity=0,
            cluster_name='eks-dev',
            masters_role=eks_admin_role,
            core_dns_compute_type=eks.CoreDnsComputeType.EC2,
            version=eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_20,
            role=node_role
        )
```

Comment: The post you shared is awesome. But I am new to both CDK and Kubernetes and the post is very high level. I am not able to get through some things in this blog. Any changes that you can suggest in the above URL that I provided can be of little help? Hope you understand. Or if you can share some detail blog like this to get more idea

Answer (score 0):

The code here is looking for a full KubernetesVersion object, not a string.
Take a look at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_eks/KubernetesVersion.html#aws_cdk.aws_eks.KubernetesVersion
So you could do something like (forgive me this is untested, as I usually use TypeScript for CDK):

```
version = aws_eks.KubernetesVersion().V1_20
```

or maybe:

```
version = aws_eks.KubernetesVersion.of("v1_20") #string may be something else, try it and see
```

Comment: Tried, but showing AMI error and python error respectively. (See attached image above)